# Applying the same change function to multiple divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, event-handling

What is the best way to bind a functions to multiple div's?

```
$('#trigger1').change(function(){
   // same code
});

$('#trigger3').change(function(){
   // same code
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either use class *(imo is class the best way)*

```
    <div class="trigger"></div>
    <div class="trigger"></div>

$('.trigger').change(function(){

});
```

or do this

```
$('#trigger1,#trigger3').change(function(){

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can include multiple ids in the same function call:

```
$('#trigger1, #trigger3').change(function(){
   // code goes here
});
```

Or you can give them the same class, e.g. triggerClass and then call it like such:

```
$('.triggerClass').change(function(){
   // code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

add a common class name to those div

```
<div class="myClass" id="trigger1">
</div>

<div class="myClass"  id="trigger2">
</div>
```

here is the script for it

```
$(".myClass").click(function(){
// your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#trigger1, #trigger3').change(some_function);

Or:

$('#trigger1').add('#trigger3').change(some_function);
```

Answer (score 1):

simply apply a same class to all elements then write

```
$('.classname').change(function(){

});
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use

```
$('#trigger1, #trigger3').change(function(){
   same code
});
```

to group the triggers

Answer (score 1):

Add a common class:

```
<div class="rowTrigger">trigger 1</div>
<div class="rowTrigger">trigger 2</div>
```

Script

```
$(function(){
   $("body").on("click", ".rowTrigger", function(e){ 
      e.preventDefault();
      var row = $(this); //row element
   });
});
```

each "rowTrigger" will fire on the "click" handler, this can be changed to other or multiple events. See 
http://api.jquery.com/on/ for more detail. 
The scope of the events handled can be changed by changing "body" to "table" for example, so it will only fire when those 'div' rows from a table are clicked.

More simply it can be written as (firing for 'click' and 'hover' ... but you get the idea) :

```
$("div.rowTrigger").on("click hover", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var row = $(this); //row element
   //some extra code
});
```